# what's R save terminal flag?

Tags: c++, sockets, r

When I save a R object through RConnection, how to determine when the data is end in the RConnction's other side?

I print the data as integer. It seams the data was end with -2. Is there any official document?

Thanks
Dma

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-May/060896.html).

Comment: sorry about that. Never happen next time.

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of docs online, but it depends what RConnection are you using on what devide for what device....

anyway, assuming you are working with symbian, this might help

http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/guide/Communications-Infrastructure-subsystem-guide/esock/SocketsClientGuide/RConnectionOverview.html

Comment: why dont you just go to the R reference page and read the info there?
# Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.

svn checkout http://r-connect.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ r-connect-read-only